# Javascript wait until elements are loaded using setInterval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, setinterval

I am building a module that will display banners on website with ajax call. There are 2 main parts of code:

1. banner.js that is inserted to head asynchronously. This javascript makes ajax call and inserts banners retrieved from ajax call to page placeholders.
2. Webmaster can insert each banner placeholder to any parts of page like this: `<div id="banner1"></div>`

Webmaster can define in admin up to 5 banners and insert the same number of placeholders. Problem is because ajax call defined in banner.js can return banners before the rest of html and placeholders are loaded. I could load banners.js before ending `</body>` tag, but this won't be optimal solution because some elements can delay DOM parsing and banners won't be loaded so fast.

So far the only solution I found is this:

```
var bannerScriptListener1 = setInterval(function(){ 
  if(jQuery("#banner1").length>0){                                           
    clearInterval(bannerScriptListener1)    
    jQuery("#banner1").html(banners[1].html)
  }
},10) 
var bannerScriptListener2 = setInterval(function(){ 
  if(jQuery("#banner2").length>0){                                           
    clearInterval(bannerScriptListener2)    
    jQuery("#banner1").html(banners[2].html)
  }
},10) 
//same for banner 3,4,5
```

How bad is that solution? I tested it using Google Task Manager tool and there wasn't much difference in client memory consuming. But I may be missing something. Is there any better solution?

EDIT:
I am giving entire html example to show the problem. I don't have control over other elements, the only control I have is control over banner.js, php file that is called with ajax call within banners.js and I can tell where webmaster can insert div placeholders. banner.js can be inserted into head, but I don't have control to which priority order. This is just very simple example, in reality with platforms like Magento there are many more files and scripts, different modules that can make mess.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="banners.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="othermodulescript1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="othermodulescript2.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="banner1"></div>
  <!--Some more elements-->
  <div>lorem ipsum</div>

  <div>lorem ipsum</div>
  <!--Example of script from another module that sometimes takes 3 seconds to load
  I don't have control over this-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/externalscript.js"></script>
  <!--Some more elements-->
  <div id="banner2"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use the JQuery function to defer the insertion of the ajaxed banners to the document.ready event. Aka `$(function() { ... do stuff that has to wait for doc ready here ... }):`

Comment: Since you're already using jQuery, wouldn't the classic `$( document ).ready(function() {})` solve this issue?

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: The vanilla version is `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { ... });` Or move the banner ajaxing script to the bottom of the body.

Comment: @shilly I am aware of this function but this is not suitable solution for my case because some other external script can block DOM loading and it can delay banner displaying for more than 5s. If there is 1 single js external file taking 5 seconds to be loaded it will display banners 5 seconds after page content has been already displayed. And it is not very rare that there is at least 1 external js file taking more than 2 seconds to be loaded.

Comment: @EatPeanutButter see previous comment.

Comment: Since you have control over which scripts you run/load and in which roder, why not always force the headers to render first before you do the external script that can block DOM? All DOM blocking should be deferred to as late as possible so you get nice render times. Load html/css -> load banners -> render banners --> load all other scripts.

Comment: I don't have this control, my module will be installed to other sites. banner.js will be inserted to head by any order. If some other module comes after mine it won't be the last js inside head. Placeholders will be inserted by client inside body into .phtml file like this: `<div id='banner1'></div>`

Comment: I think I'm understanding the problem less the more I read it. Your banner.js file is creating the DOM containers and loading the files?  Or is it just loading the banner files?

Comment: This is why we invented things like require and module loaders, to prevent bad 3rd party code from trashing our render times. :( I'm sorry, but we'd have to go over everything that you can and can't change and their effects to find something better than setInterval. If you could post a code sample of a full page (the relevant parts) with the (variable) orders the scripts can load in and explain which scripts can block DOM, there might be a more elegant solution to be found. At the moment I can only say, maybe try placing all the intervals into one interval.

Comment: @EatPeanutButter I edited question to make it more clear. banner.js doesn't insert placeholders, placeholders are inserted via .phtml files manually banner.js just gets banners via ajax call.

Comment: For clarity: banners.js is the file you are writing? And the intention is to provide web masters with a html template,the banners.js file and variable other modules, where they can insert extra html with various ids to render banners for them without them needing to code the ajax/html insertion? But the issue is that you're not the only module, so the things written by other people can also put scripts inside the <head> tag that will block DOM and hence, decrease render time on banners.

Comment: why not use `$('.placeholder-wrapper').ready(function() {});`. Its the same like doucment ready but only for a element

Comment: I made one more edit to question to make further explanation. The purpose is to give webmaster option to insert dynamic banners to existing pages. Ajax call is used to prevent cache conflicts because banners shouldn't be cached. And yes, other people can insert scripts inside the head or body tag, I don't have control over that, some websites have installed 30+ different modules and everything is possible.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, but sadly you can't prevent the render delay. This is a prime example why so many scripts don't belong in the header of a page and I wished tutorials would teach new devs the differences between head and body scripts.

Answer (score 0):

That is no good idea. If you do an AJAX call, you can use the onload-Event to put your code in.

```
$("#myDiv").load("/ajax.js", function() {
   // do stuff after load complete
   console.log("done loading ajax.js");
});
```

Another idea if you put code with PHP:

```
<script>
function loadComplete() { console.log("load complete."); }
</script>
<script src="filetoload.js" onload="loadComplete();"></script>
```

Comment: I think you didn't read my question properly. The problem is not so much about when ajax call is loaded but about when placeholders to where I should insert content from ajax call are loaded.

Comment: After loading you can fill any id. So you may put something like `document.getElementById("banner1").innerHTML = yourdata;` into the loadComplete() method.

Comment: This won't work if #banner1 hasn't been loaded yet because banner.js ajax call completed before #banner1 placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

You could at least clean up your code by producing a jQuery plugin to handle the loading.

This is the easiest way to re-use your code.

```js
// File: jquery.script-listener.js
(function($) {
  $.fn.scriptListener = function(options) {
    var $target = $(this);
    var config = $.extend({
      onLoadSetValue : null,
      delay : 1000
    }, options);
    var pid = setInterval(function() {
      if ($target.length > 0) {
        clearInterval(pid);
        $target.html(config.onLoadSetValue ? config.onLoadSetValue() : '');
      }
    }, config.delay);
  }
})(jQuery);

// File: banners.js
var banners = [
  { html : '<h1>Hello World #1</h1>' },
  { html : '<h1>Hello World #2</h1>' },
  { html : '<h1>Hello World #3</h1>' },
  { html : '<h1>Hello World #4</h1>' },
  { html : '<h1>Hello World #5</h1>' }
]; // Returned from AJAX call.

// Loop over all possible banners.
for (var i = 0; i < banners.length; i++) {
  $('#banner-' + (i + 1)).scriptListener((function(id) {
    return {
      onLoadSetValue : function() {
        return banners[id].html;
      },
      delay : 10
    }
  })(i));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="banner-1"></div>
<div id="banner-2"></div>
<div id="banner-3"></div>
<div id="banner-4"></div>
<div id="banner-5"></div>
```